# Subtractive Magic and the Pristinely Ungifted in the Sword of Truth

Tags: the-sword-of-truth, terry-goodkind

I've always been confused by the relation between the "Pristinely Ungifted" and Subtractive Magic. Because Subtractive Magic has some poorly-defined ties to death, it still affects the Pristinely Ungifted. This would seem to contradict the fact, established by the ancient wizards (who had both sides of the Gift), that the Pristinely Ungifted have no connection to any magic!

For example, the barriers placed around the Bandakar were still able to kill them, even though they're supposed to be immune to magic. The Chainfire spell also affected them, running primarily on Subtractive Magic.

Is this just a plot hole? Or are there some subtle rules that it actually does conform to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The short answer:** The Pristinely Ungifted are only invulnerable to [Additive Magic](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Additive_Magic). They can still be affected by the much rarer and death-oriented [Subtractive Magic](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Subtractive_Magic).

> **Subtractive magic used to be common in those born with The Gift, but would eventually die out, such that the gifted would be born only with Additive magic for centuries.** This was cause by the actions of a team of one hundred wizards from the New World who used their magic to lock Subtractive magic away within the Temple of the Winds. (emphasis mine)

Anything that used, combined, or depended on Subtractive Magic could still affect them. Subtractive Magic altered reality by removing elements of reality and transferring them to the Underworld.

It was only the rarity of Subtractive Magic that made them believe they couldn't be affected by it. Nor did the books explain this particular topic well, so it was easy for the readers to be confused as well.

Comment: But Alric Rahl's spell that creates the Pristinely Ungifted as a side-effect was created during an era when Subtractive Magic was very common, surely they wouldn't have written down that the Pristinely Ungifted were immune to _all_ magic if they tested them for it, and it's inconceivable that they would have only tested half of their magic, so wont were they to make human weapons out of wizards using both sides of the Gift.

Comment: Only Wizards had regular access to Subtractive Magic, so it might have fallen out of regular lore over time. And since Subtractive magic tends to be a bit destructive, it would be harder to test without killing someone...

Comment: They did find a journal from ancient wizards, (iirc from the statue overlooking the Bandakar) that detailed the decision to evict the Pristinely Ungifted, and all the things they tried before, which included the assertion that the PU were immune to all magic.

EDIT: Though the PU _had_ fallen out of the lore, such that they were the merest rumors to a few wizards among the best and brightest remaining during the books.

Comment: From http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Subtractive_Magic: Subtractive magic also allows someone to destroy shields created from Additive magic and directly kill Pristinely Ungifted.

Comment: Also, Pristinely Ungifted could be affected by Additive magic indirectly. For example: use Additive magic to blow up something, and use the debris to kill them, as the debris are material.

Answer (score 0):

The Pristinely Ungifted were only immune to Additive Magic. **No one** was immune to the effects of Subtractive Magic.  It was tied to the Underworld, the land of death, and no one can escape death.

Comment: I think the Mord-Sith were immune. Rikka disguised herself as a civilian to trick a Sister of the Dark into using an attack spell on her, and promptly captured the Sister's power. Though the book doesn't explicitly say whether Sister Tahirah cast an Additive or Subtractive spell. And in Book 4, Cara captured Legate Rishi's magic when he unleashed what sounded like a mix of Additive and Subtractive spells at her. Again, it wasn't stated explicitly, but the description made it sound like it was a mix of + and - he used.

Comment: Whatever he used, she did capture both the Additive and Subtractive sides of his magic. (EDIT) - Their immunity would have been only partial. I remembered that some spells, like Chainfire and the spell used on Berdine in Book 3, could affect them if they weren't aware of the spell in time to capture it.